# How to Log data in a SaaS Cloud Shop

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

As I now learned, it is not permitted by Shopware to set the permission "log_entry" and therefore use the API endpoint "api/log-entry" to add entries to the Shopware log in a SaaS Instance. :(

Would be the best solution to add an own "Log" Entity for that and provide the data to the shop owner also via an own listing view in the administration?

If so, that would be very bad, because it would be so much easier to just use the log feature Shopware already implemented.

Or is there another easier opportunity for that?

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom module you can [use the Admin Extension SDK to dispatch a notification](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/notification) from within the iframe. Notifications of the `error` variant will also be persisted to `log_entry`.

If your app is subscribing to webhooks and that's when you want to log stuff, you'll probably have to go the route you described or preferably even log on the app server. While it may be inconvenient this measure was likely taken to disencourage using the Shopware log tables because they should be reserved for errors and the likes happening within the system and should not be opened up to apps logging errors happening on their side.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I already use the notification and show that an error occured and that the log should be considered to get more detailed information on that. So that is not an option because the message is quite large and should also be persited to pull it up later.

But good to know that its the best way to implement the logging into the app.

Comment: "Notifications of the error variant will also be persisted to log_entry."
Hm, so is this then also viewable by the shop owner or is only Shopware having access to it?

Comment: They should be visible to the shop owner under Settings > System > Event Logs

Comment: Dang It. Also not available in a SaaS shop. From the Shopware docs:
Event logs

Please note that this article is only for users of a self-hosted store. This is not relevant for users of a Shopware 6 Cloud environment.

The cloud system is becoming more and more unsympathetic to me. But the biggest hurdle for developers is that you can't debug anything and you are not able to test your integration in an actual cloud instance. :(